# conditional loop printing text and icon

Tags: macros, conditionals, loops

I'm new in the Latex world. I'm writing a little guide and I've choose Latex, in particular Texmaker for writing it.

I'm trying to do a loop for printing some instruction as File -> Save as -> Ok.

this is my code
preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\Iconmenu}[1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{#1}}%
\newcommand*{\UnrollMenu}[2]{%
    \foreach \x in {#2} {%
        \ifthenelse{\x\equal{#1}{true}}{%
            $\x\Iconmenu{#1}\boldsymbol{\rightarrow}$}%     
        {%
        $\x$}%
}}%
```

and this is the call in the document:

```
\UnrollMenu{appearance}{Appearance,Themes}
```

appearance is an icon in jpg format
I'd like to print it in this way:

Appearance [image: appearance.jpg] -> Themes

but I can't figure out, someone could give a hint?

Comment: Where is `\foreach` defined? Is it in a package?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the packages.

Comment: Try replacing `\x\equal{#1}{true}` by `\equal{#1}{\x}`. Note that `\equal` is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks it works! I was going crazy! 
little question: if I want to it bold, how i put the \textbf without generating an error?

Comment: if you answer your question i mark it as solution

Comment: i got it! simply add \boldsymbol before \x
thanks a lot man!

Comment: You can have a look at my package [`menukeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) which provides want you want I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code comes from the way you use `\equal`. Instead of having `\x\equal{#1}{true}`, you should use `\equal{#1}{\x}`.

Note that `\equal` is case-sensitive, and some converting should be used if you need the filename lowercased but the displayed name starting with an uppercase.

The [`menukeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package provided by Tobi is indeed of interest in your case. Support for menu icons could be interesting.